# How to find unique rows in data frame in R

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
> mydata

S.no  ID1   ID2

1.    234   ABC
2.    345   ASD
3.    789   ASE
4.    567   ASW
5.    567   ASQ
6.    789   KLM
7.    345   GHJ
```

For each unique value of `ID1` i want all the values listed in `ID2`, eg.:

```
S.no  ID1   Count  ID2

1.    234    1     ABC
2.    345    2     ASD
                   GHJ
3.    789    2     ASE
                   KLM
4.    567    2     ASW
                   ASQ
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`, grouped by "ID1", we get the first element of "S.no", number of rows (`.N`), and `paste` the "ID2" elements together.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,list(S.no=S.no[1L], Count=.N, 
                ID2= paste(ID2, collapse=' ')) , ID1]
#   ID1 S.no Count     ID2
#1: 234    1     1     ABC
#2: 345    2     2 ASD GHJ
#3: 789    3     2 ASE KLM
#4: 567    4     2 ASW ASQ
```

---

Or using `dplyr`, we can use the same methodology

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(ID1) %>%
    summarise(S.no = S.no[1L], Count=n(), ID2= paste(ID2, collapse=' '))
```